# Spring Boot: trigger InputStream Download in Browser

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to download a file:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

@GetMapping("/file")
public void file(@RequestParam("path") String path, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    InputStream inStream = fmService.downloadFile("https://" + path);
    IOUtils.copy(inStream, response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

But when I visit localhost:8080/file?path=/Documents... a download gets not triggered.
If I use a txt file in the path, then the content of it is shown to me in the browser, but when I'm using a pdf file nothing really happens. Having 200 response code but no download.
How can I use spring-boot to download the files?

And the next step would be to call this spring-boot api endpoint and download from an Angular frontend.
I think the output must be different too then or?

Comment: Ok, if I add response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName); the (4 Byte) .txt File gets downloaded in the Browser. But tryed the same with a pdf and this did not work. Does this maybe have something to do with how I use the stream and/or the copy method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the following header so that the browser knows to download a file from the returned response instead of displaying on browser. See
https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-boot-blog-app/blob/master/src/main/java/gt/app/modules/file/FileDownloadUtil.java

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "a.txt");
```

**A working GetMapping:**

```
@GetMapping
void d(HttpServletResponse r) throws IOException {
  r.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "a.txt");
  r.getOutputStream().print("ABCD");
  r.getOutputStream().flush();
}


//Or return input stream:
 
@GetMapping("/is")
void d(HttpServletResponse r) throws IOException {
    r.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "a.txt");

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("Some test string".getBytes()); //or any input stream

    org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, r.getOutputStream());
    r.getOutputStream().flush();
}
```

Downloading file from angular app:

This gets tricky and needs to be done in three steps:

- a first call to get direct link to the file
- render the link in anchor tag `<a href=`
- have user click the link to do the file download

You can refer to this: https://blog.gtiwari333.com/2017/01/angularjs-download-file-from-server.html